# When using getJSON, how to capture the response data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

something strange is going on... I have he following function:

```
getInviteLink : function() {
    var me = this,
        invite_url;

    $.getJSON('get_invite_code.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data.invite_url);
        invite_url = data.invite_url;
    });

    console.log(invite_url)

    return invite_url;
},
```

When this runs, for first console log is returning the correct value. However, on the second console log there is nothing. Why isn't the invite_url able to be set from inside the getJSON function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because the getJSON method is asynchronous. What's happening...

```
getInviteLink : function() {  // this function is called...
    var me = this,   
    invite_url;               // happens right away

    $.getJSON('get_invite_code.json', function(data) {
        // Step 2, these statements don't happen until later 
        // -- when the response is received
        console.log(data.invite_url);  // this
        invite_url = data.invite_url;
    });  //  Step 1. the getJSON is called right away

    console.log(invite_url) // this happens right after the
                            // the getJSON is called, but before
                            // it gets a response. Thus no data when the log
                            // statement is invoked

    return invite_url;      // also no data (yet) when this return statement
                            // is executed
},
```

**Added** To fix your software, you need to realize that you can't do anything with the `invite_url` until after the JSON response is received from the server. -- And it may never be received if your client ends up with a network problem or a server problem.

You can pass a function to your getJSON call. The function will make use of the invite_url. In the meantime, you can do other things for your client.

If there is nothing for your software to do until you get the response, then set a busy indicator (a rotating circle or something), then launch the json request and have the function cancel the busy indicator when you get the response back.

See the jQuery json docs for more about this.

Comment: Very helpful thanks, any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

you can not get invite_url as return value useing getJSON in about code. need to refactor with callback functions if you want to use inviteURL.

in this case if you see the order of the console. its will execute invite_url first and then data.invite_url.  the reason being getJSON is asynchronous call. to make this working you need to call get JSON with async: false with is not possible to you need to use $.ajax with datatyoe json. following example will match what you need.

```
getInviteLink: function() {
    var me = this,
        invite_url;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_invite_code.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.invite_url);
            invite_url = data.invite_url;
        }
    });

    console.log(invite_url)

    return invite_url;
},
```

I if return is not mandatory here i would recommend to refactor code and use callback functions instead async false. so you can use getJSON

Answer (score 1):

It does set it, but asynchronously.  The callback function is only invoked once the server response has arrived.  The `$.getJSON` function will return as soon as the request is sent, though, so the "second" console.log will actually happen first, before the callback function has been invoked.

You can't write a function like this that synchronously returns the result of an asynchronous server request.

Comment: Suggestion to revise? Inser the return inside the success?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot return the value.  You cannot make a synchronous function that returns the value from an asynchronous request.  The best you can do is use the value in the success callback.